# Parse cloud code not working as expected with pointers (query.include)

Tags: javascript, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

The database has a class "Photos". This class has a pointer to "User" class.

I use this cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("AllPhotos", function(request, response) {
var query = new Parse.Query("Photos");

var userPointer = {"__type":"Pointer","className":"User","objectId":request.params.userId}; 

query.equalTo("active", true);
query.equalTo("userId", userPointer); 
query.descending("createdAt");
query.include("_User");  
query.find({
success: function(results) {

    response.success(results);
},
error: function() {
    response.error("Error 000");
}
});
});
```

When I query "AllPhotos" I expected to get the User object (with username, name etc) without another query but this is the result:

```
<Photos: 0x6080004a0240, objectId: k2SvMOVJ7s, localId: (null)> {
active = 1;
image = "<PFFile: 0x60800064cdb0>";
likes = 0;
userId = "<PFUser: 0x6080002e9300, objectId: gHfS6dzrag, localId: (null)>";
}
```

It just give me the objectId and I need to query again the user class to get username and name.

How can I retrieve without doing another query?

Answer (score 0):

What type is userId? It looks like your userId is actually a pointer to the user? If so, you need to call `query.include("userId")`, not `query.include("_User")`.  _User is the under the hood class of Parse.user. WHen you use include, you need to include the *field name* a pointer is stored under.

Comment: I tried with "userId" also. I don't know what happened. I updated the parse server and now it's working! Thank you!

Comment: @Jake T. could you help me also with a similar issue?Thank you

Comment: I might be able to if you link me to a question.